# Memory is not released despite calling delete[]

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

This is a very strange error. I have spent some time trying to resolve it, but i am simply lost.

I have a recursive function, implementing a form of Minimax algorithm. There are ChessBoard objects that are implemented into a tree by having a link to a previous and next moves. But that's not where the issue is.

Because the whole tree takes a lot of memory, i wanted to implement something akin to IFrame and PFrame design of the video compression. Each board can be in one of two states: `IFrame` is when it stores an array of all the pieces at their positions (this would make analysis of the board's position faster), `PFrame` is when it only stores the differences between the previous position and itself (which should take up much less space in memory, only 4 cells are assumed to change and that's only when casting). I have two methods:

```
void ChessBoard::makeIFrame()
{
    if(!board)
    {
        //++chessBoardArrayCreateCount;
        board = new ChessPiece[param.cellCount];
        std::copy(from->board, from->board+param.cellCount, board);
        for(size_t i=0; i<4; ++i)
        {
            if(changes[i].pos==param.cellCount)
            {
                break;
            }
            board[changes[i].pos] = changes[i].piece;
        }
    }
}

void ChessBoard::makePFrame()
{
    if(board)
    {
        //++chessBoardArrayDeleteCount;
        delete[] board;
        board=nullptr;
    }
}
```

I can confirm that `makePFrame` method is executed, but i can see that it has no impact on the number of the objects that fit in the memory.

I an unsure if it matters, but the process doing the calculation runs in a separate `std::thread`, but i never manipulate the board's state when calculation is happening from any other place.

Comment: how do you measure the _impact on the number of the objects that fit in memory_?

Comment: Delete the objects in board array, then the board itself.

Comment: "But that's not where the issue is."....issues usually are where you least expect them (otherwise they wouldnt be issues ;)

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Something crashes?

Comment: One of the challenges of computer chess games is the amount of memory used for prediction or analyzation of moves.  You will not have enough memory for each possible move.

Comment: If you want to implement your own garbage collection, then use an array for allocating your moves.  You can mark which slots are in use.

Comment: Issuing a call to `delete[]` does not guarantee the memory is returned to the OS or if anything you observe will be obvious.  Sometimes a call to `delete` almost seems like nothing happened.  What is really happening is that the heap manager marked those allocated spaces as "free for later use if necessary", and attempting to access those locations lead to undefined behavior.  Did you actually go the step further, regardless of what you may have measured, and verify that you cannot create more `board` instances due to conceived memory conditions?

Comment: @GianPaolo I limit my program to a specific size in memory and let it run throught the algorythm. Once out of memory exception is thrown i display how many objects were create and how many were destroyed (object creation is done by the factory and object destruction is then counted in destructor.

Comment: Why is board  not a `std::vector`? You don't need to check for nullptr when calling delete btw

Comment: How do we know there aren't other places in your program that will leak memory?  How do we know you're not properly pairing up the `makeIFrame` and `makePFrame` calls in tandem.  If you were to strip this code down to only those two functions, would you see the memory not being released, [as seen here?](https://www.ideone.com/Acx360).  There are 100,000 calls to allocate and free memory.  Your claim with the code you posted suggests that the simple program at the link would also show signs of undesired memory usage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I never made any such claims. As i have said in my question my code has minimax algorythm that builds the tree. There's no such thing in your code. If you want to see the complete code... ok: https://github.com/Volodya/almostuni-2302-chess The thing is that i realise that if i just give entire code nobody will actually read it.

Comment: So basically your code has potential memory leaks in the code you didn't show us.  As to what I posted, it removes anything that has no bearing whatsoever on memory allocation -- that is what you posted and I tried to make is a [mcve] to show it isn't what you posted that is the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, as i have explained in my question, that isn't what i am asking. Can my code have a memory leak in the code i have now showed you? Yes, potentially it does. It is very unlikely that it has significant influence on the issue i am trying to resolve right now. At this moment, ...... well, i''ve just realised i'm beginning to retype my question.

Comment: @v010dya • _Can my code have a memory leak in the code i have now showed you?_  Yes.